# How to remove code analysis from ida pro as olly debugger?

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, ida

(1) I reverse engineer a program in Ida pro and I see lots of "db" instructions
(2) In olly debugger ,"db" instruction can be remove by option "remove code analysis from this module". 
(3) how i can remove code analysis from Ida pro?
(4) i have also tried code deobfuscator plugin in ida but that not seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to "undefine" bytes. There are also other possibilities depending on what you want exactly.

Select something in the main window then press one of those key:

- 'U' for undefine
- 'C' for code
- 'D' for data
- 'A' for ASCII string

See the "Edit" menu for more options.